# Special functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get a picture like the following:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e6/Airy-3d.svg

What am I doing wrong?

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-1:.1:1,-1:.1:1);
surf(x,y,(2*besselj(1,2*pi*sqrt(x.^2+ y.^2)/sqrt(x.^2+ y.^2)).^2)
```

Also... kind of a side note, but if I used ndgrid instead of meshgrid here my x's and y's would switch right?

Comment: The `surf` line has mismatched parentheses, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things I see wrong with the equation:

- There is a missing close parentheses somewhere in your equation, perhaps after the first `sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)`? In the equation, it appears that you are dividing `sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)` by itself, which is probably not what you want to do and is why I was thinking you were missing a parentheses from around there.
- You will probably want to perform element-wise division using `./` instead of matrix right division using `/` (see [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) for more detail).

In addition, you will want to change the [`'FaceColor'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surfaceplotproperties.html#FaceColor) of the surface object to `'none'` so that only the edges of the mesh are displayed:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1:.1:1,-1:.1:1);
z = ...  %# Compute your z in some way
surf(x,y,z,'FaceColor','none');
```