# Graphing special functions in Matlab (2D Bessel)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to essentially get something like this where I can see clear ripples at the base but otherwise it's like a Gaussian: 
[image]

This is kind of unsatisfactory because the ripples aren't very noticeable, it has a very gritty quality that obscures the image a bit, and if you move the graph so that it's just in 2D (so it looks like a circle) I'm not even sure if it's quite like how it should be (the concentric circles seem to be more evenly spaced in the real thing). So, is there a better way to do this?

```
a = 2*pi;
[X Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.01:1,-1:0.01:1);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
f = (2*besselj(1,a*R(:))./R(:)).^2;
mesh(X,Y,reshape(f,size(X)));
axis vis3d;
```

Comment: You basically asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786302/special-functions-in-matlab. Please refrain from posting the same question multiple times. If you need to refine your previous question, click the edit link to modify it. If you can't see an "edit" link under the question, it is probably because you have 3 different accounts (http://stackoverflow.com/users). Try getting an OpenID login and have these accounts merged so you don't have to duplicate questions, which is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the colormap, or change the surface properties and show shape with reflections. Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surface_props.html) to see all you can do. For example:

```
a = 2*pi;
[X Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.01:1,-1:0.01:1);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
f = (2*besselj(1,a*R(:))./R(:)).^2;
h=mesh(X,Y,reshape(f,size(X)));
axis vis3d;
%# change from mesh to solid surface with no lines
set(h,'FaceColor','interp','edgeColor','none','facelighting','phong');
%# set reflectance
material shiny
%# add light. Change the position to see different reflections
light('Position',[10 0 10],'Style','local');
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

#### Surf

[image]

#### Code

```
a = 2*pi;
[X Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
f = (2*besselj(1,a*R(:))./R(:)).^2;
h=surf(X,Y,reshape(f,size(X)));
axis vis3d;
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0)
```